# How do I get Age distribution list by grouping

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I want to return a List which contains data related to the Age Distribution (Eg. For Age 0-9 there are 10 persons, for 10-19 there are 7 persons etc)

This is my query :-

```
 public List<ReportHelper> GetAgeDistribution(int userId)
        {
            var itemList = (from item in this.ObjectContext.TreeMembers
                            where item.UserId == userId
                            group (DateTime.Now - (item.Birthdate ?? DateTime.Now)).Days/365.25
                            by ((DateTime.Now - (item.Birthdate ?? DateTime.Now)).Days / 365.25) / 9);

            List<ReportHelper> list = new List<ReportHelper>();

            foreach (var item in itemList)
                list.Add(new ReportHelper { Data = item.Count(), Label = item.Key + "-" + (item.Key + 9) });


            return list;
        }
```

When I run this query I get dbarithmeticexpression exception :

```
DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.
```

How do I solve this error? I know Entity Framework 4 is not able to translate my expression to plain old sql. How can I hint it what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: unless BirthDate is of type `DateTime?` you won't need `item.Birthdate ?? DateTime.Now` because DateTime is not nullable.

Comment: @Zebi :- BirthDate is DateTime? otherwise the code won't even compile. Problem is not of any nullable type. Problem is EF cannot translate Linq to plain old sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saeed is right; the best way to go here is to use the canonical `DiffYears` function through the [**`EntityFunctions.DiffYears`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.diffyears.aspx) method.

In addition, the logic you have for dividing ages into the buckets `[0 - 9]` years, `[10 - 19]` years  etc. seems incorrect; you should divide complete years by `10`, not `9`.

This query should work fine:

```
var itemList = from item in this.ObjectContext.TreeMembers
               where item.UserId == userId
               let age = EntityFunctions.DiffYears
                              (item.Birthdate, DateTime.Now) ?? 0
               group item by age / 10 into ageGroup
               select new
               {
                   AgeInCompletedDecades = ageGroup.Key, 
                   Count = ageGroup.Count() 
               };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't do this in EF:

```
DateTime.Now - (item.Birthdate ?? DateTime.Now))....
```

you can use [**Entity canonical functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for this purpose.

In fact you can't do `DateTime1 - DateTime2` in EF.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to change 365.25 to 365 (so it's an `int` like the `Days` property).

Answer (score 0):

What if you converted your dates to numerical values using the `mydate.ToOADate()` function?  This function converts dates to a double value where the whole number portion of the double represents what day it is and the fractional part of the double represents a fractional day (i.e. time of day).

I don't know much about Entity arithmetic, but if the dates were doubles then it might not throw that exception - just a guess.